# Get the content of a public website with Python

Tags: python, excel, vba, web, screen-scraping

I am faced with a real mystery:

VBA

```
 .send "land_abk=sh&ger_name=Norderstedt&order_by=2&ger_id=X1526"
```

Python

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.24.0', 'Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate', 'Accept': '*/*', 'Connection': 'keep-alive','Referer': 'https://url'}
```

A click on link leads to the last child-ULR and to the details. I tried really everthing to get data from the 3. site, with **POST, GET, VBA, PYTHON-Referer**, wihtout success. I just get **header response 200** & **header-content**, but not a single letter from the sourcecode, just an error without any description. The only way to open this 3rd page without error and with content is to click the link on the 2nd page. This is a completely public website, no reason to build in referer or any other encryption. So what is the problem and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your headers should work fine, as long as you include the correct referrer. Maybe there is something wrong in your way of receiving the html. This works for me:

**Using urllib3**

```py
import urllib3
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.zvg-portal.de/index.php?button=showZvg&zvg_id=755&land_abk=sh"
headers = {
    "Referer": "https://www.zvg-portal.de/index.php?button=Suchen",
}

http = urllib3.PoolManager()
response = http.request("GET", URL, headers=headers)
html = response.data.decode("ISO-8859-1")

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
print(soup.select_one("tr td b").text)
# >> 0061 K 0012/ 2019
```

**Using requests**

```py
import requests

URL = "https://www.zvg-portal.de/index.php?button=showZvg&zvg_id=755&land_abk=sh"

headers = {
    "Referer": "https://www.zvg-portal.de/index.php?button=Suchen",
}
html = requests.get(URL, headers=headers).text

print("Versteigerung im Wege der Zwangsvollstreckung" in html)
# >> True
```

**Using Python 2:**

```
import urllib2

URL = "https://www.zvg-portal.de/index.php?button=showZvg&zvg_id=755&land_abk=sh"

req = urllib2.Request(URL)
req.add_header("Referer", "https://www.zvg-portal.de/index.php?button=Suchen")
html = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()

print("Versteigerung im Wege der Zwangsvollstreckung" in html)
# >> True
```

Comment: 'soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')' 's.headers = headers print(soup.select_one('tr td b').text)'  this happens: **(AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text')**   Access to header is possible with vba too, but no to the content!

Comment: You're not actually using your custom headers in `r = s.post(...)`. Should be:`r = s.post(
        "https://www.zvg-portal.de/index.php?button=showZvg&zvg_id=755&land_abk=sh",
        headers=headers)`

Comment: I use Python 3.9.4, with urllib3. **(IDLE: AttributeError: module 'urllib3' has no attribute 'Request)**' Not possible to install urllib or urllib2.

Comment: I've added an example using urllib3. Next time, please take a look at the documentation: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html

Comment: Thank you friend! Because of 10 lines of code I have broken my head almost 10 hours sleepless! So a referer is actually built in here after all?! Can I ask you for one more favor? Is it possible to set a referer when opening a url in browser? I want to open the pdf-link in the browser with python, this site behaves without referer just as piggy with an error!

Comment: You're welcome! Most browser do not provide an easy way to spoof the referrer header. But you can try to download the PDF using Python as well: https://stackabuse.com/download-files-with-python/